# display cart information within li of cart menu item

Tags: menus, hooks, navigation

I am using this code in the functions.php of my theme, in order to add cart information next to the cart menu item.

However, this code adds this information outside the `<li>` and I would like the information to be into the `<li>`.

Can you help me change this code in order to display the info within the `<li>`?

Thanks

```
/**
 * This function adds the WooCommerce or Easy Digital Downloads cart icons/items to the top_nav menu area as the last item.
 */
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'my_wp_nav_menu_items', 10, 2 );
function my_wp_nav_menu_items( $items, $args, $ajax = false ) {
    // Top Navigation Area Only
    if ( ( isset( $ajax ) && $ajax ) || ( property_exists( $args, 'theme_location' ) && $args->theme_location === 'primary' ) ) {
        // WooCommerce
        if ( class_exists( 'woocommerce' ) ) {
            $css_class = 'menu-item menu-item-type-cart menu-item-type-woocommerce-cart';
            // Is this the cart page?
            if ( is_cart() )
                $css_class .= ' current-menu-item';
            //$items .= '<li class="' . esc_attr( $css_class ) . '">';
                $items .= '<a class="cart-contents" href="' . esc_url( WC()->cart->get_cart_url() ) . '">';
                    // $items .= wp_kses_data( WC()->cart->get_cart_total() ) . ' - <span class="count">' .  wp_kses_data( sprintf( _n( '%d item', '%d items', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(), 'simple-shop' ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ) ) . '</span>';
                $items .= ' (<span class="count">' .  wp_kses_data( sprintf( _n( '%d', '%d', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(), 'simple-shop' ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ) ) . '</span>)';
                $items .= '</a>';
            //$items .= '</li>';
        }
    }
    return $items;
}
/**
 * This function updates the Top Navigation WooCommerce cart link contents when an item is added via AJAX.
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'my_woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments' );
function my_woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments( $fragments ) {
    // Add our fragment
    $fragments['li.menu-item-type-woocommerce-cart'] = my_wp_nav_menu_items( '', new stdClass(), true );
    return $fragments;
}
```

**EDIT (new code)**

```
 add_filter( 'wp_setup_nav_menu_item','my_item_setup' );
function my_item_setup($item) {

    if ( class_exists( 'woocommerce' ) ) {

        global $woocommerce;

        ?>
        <!--<pre><?php //var_dump( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_contents_count()  ); ?></pre>-->        
        <?php


        if ( $item->url == esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ) ) {


            //$item->title = 'MY BAG('. '<span class="count">' .  wp_kses_data( sprintf( _n( '%d', '%d', WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count(), 'simple-shop' ), WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_count() ) ) . '</span>)';

            //$item->title = 'MY BAG('. '<span class="count">' .  wp_kses_data( sprintf( _n( '%d', '%d', $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count(), 'simple-shop' ), $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count() ) ) . '</span>)';


            $item->title = 'MY BAG('. '<span class="count">' .  $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_contents_count() . '</span>)';


            //$item->title = sprintf( _n( '%d', '%d', $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count();, 'simple-shop' ), $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count(); );


        }
    }
    return $item;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting the full solution I used (with two languages, to be placed in functions.php):

```
add_filter( 'wp_setup_nav_menu_item','my_item_setup' );
function my_item_setup($item) {

    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        if ( class_exists( 'woocommerce' ) ) {

            global $woocommerce;

            if ( $item->url == esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ) ) {

                if (is_null($woocommerce->cart)){

                } else {
                    if( get_locale() == 'fr_FR' ) {
                        $item->title = 'PANIER ('. '<span class="count">' .  $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_contents_count() . '</span>)';
                    } else {
                        $item->title = 'MY BAG ('. '<span class="count">' .  $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_contents_count() . '</span>)';
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
    return $item;
}


/**
 * This function updates the cart link contents when an item is added via AJAX.
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments', 'my_woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments' );
function my_woocommerce_add_to_cart_fragments( $fragments ) {
    // Add our fragment
    $fragments['li.menu-item-type-woocommerce-cart'] = my_item_setup( '');
    return $fragments;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The items in the $fragments array will replace the html contents of the element you specify as the key. In your example

```
$fragments['li.menu-item-type-woocommerce-cart'] = 'some html';
```

*some html* will be inserted in the DOM element <li class="menu-item-type-woocommerce-cart">

Here is the Javascript:

```
$( 'li.menu-item-type-woocommerce-cart' ).replaceWith( 'some html' );
```

Is there already such an element in your menu?

Comment: Hi @ChristianLescuyer, I changed my code now. and it displays well. But I still have a php issue, because some Back Office page won't display now.

Comment: Hi @Louis, if you’re happy with my answer, just approve it. 
As for your back office pages, it’s difficult to analyze without more information.